# Debugging Query execution in PHP

Tags: php, propel, execution

I have this code:

```
$room_chan = RoomChannelQuery::create()
  ->filterByChannel($hotel_channel->getChannel())
  ->filterByRoom($res_room->getRoom())
  ->findOneByIdCamera($res_room->getRoom()->getId());
```

How can I view the query execution in php ?

Comment: We'll need the `RoomChannelQuery` class.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by *query execution* ?

If you mean, dumping the sql, it can be done like that :

```
$params = array();
$sql    = BasePeer::createSelectSql($room_chan, $params);
var_dump($sql);
```

or

```
var_dump($room_chan->toString());
```

Comment: I don't know the specifics of propel, but isn't the php "standard" `__toString()`?

Comment: @KaviSiegel not really: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/blob/master/runtime/lib/query/Criteria.php#L1485-1511

Comment: Right you are then. Like I said, I don't know propel, but it is a php5 thing. Rather new though http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring